# The version of Dynamics CRM Source is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow

Tags: sql-server, ssis, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-2014, kingswaysoft

I'm running SSIS w/ Kingswaysoft on latest version of VS2017. I have created a package that executes successfully on my local computer and I have also successfully deployed the project deployment file via Integration Services Deployment Wizard to a SQL 2014 server (from the command prompt with *ISDeploymentWizard.exe*). 
Before deploying, I checked that *"TargetServerVersion"* was indeed "SQL Server 2014".

After the successfull deploy, when I manually execute the package on the target server I got the following exception:

> Data Flow Task:Error:
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ComponentVersionMism atchException:
>   The version of Dynamics CRM Source is not compatible with this version
>   of the DataFlow. [[The version or pipeline version or both for the
>   specified component is higher than the current version. This package
>   was probably created on a new version of DTS or the component than is
>   installed on the current PC.]] at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHos
>   t.HostCheckAndPerformUpgrade (IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper,
>   Int32 lPipelineVersion)

Anyone have a clue how to solve this one?

Answer (score 1):

It is likely you have a later version of our software on your development environment then the server you are deploying to. You will want to make sure both environments are using the same version of our software.

https://www.kingswaysoft.com/products/ssis-integration-toolkit-for-microsoft-dynamics-365/download

Please let us know if you still have trouble.

Comment: Hello, I have the same issue, can you please clarify, what do you mean when referring to ‘server’ in your answer?